# @media queries not running in my responsive nav bar design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am stuck with this fault, the responsive nav bar i am trying to make  using media queries is not at all responsive as the @medias seem to have no effect whatever i try .
I have tried every possible format of the media queries but all i get is unresponsiveness; please help me get over it.

I am stuck with this fault, the responsive nav bar i am trying to make  using media queries is not at all responsive as the @medias seem to have no effect whatever i try .
I have tried every possible format of the media queries but all i get is unresponsiveness; please help me get over it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Product Page</title>
        <style>
            *{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            
            body{
                background-color: antiquewhite;
                font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
            }
            
            #wrapper{
                position: relative;
            }
            li{
                list-style: none;
                
            }
            
            
            a{
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            
            header{
                width: 10s0vw;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                min-height: 75px;
                
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-around;
                align-items: center;
                background-color: aquamarine;
                
                @media screen and(max-width: 600px){
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                }
                
            }
            
            .logo{
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 60vw;
                @media screen and(max-width: 650px){
                    margin-top: 15px;
                    width: 100%;
                    posistion: relative;
                }
            }
            
            #header-img{
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 80px;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                margin-left: 10px;
                @media screen and(max-width: 650px)
                {
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }
                
            }
            
            #nav-bar{
                border: 1px solid black;
                font-weight: 400;
                
                @media screen and(max-width: 650px) {
                    margin-top: 10px;
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 0 50px;
                  
                    li{
                        padding-bottom: 0px;
                    }
                }
                
                            
            }
            
            ul{
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 35vw;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-around;
                
                @media screen and(max-width: 650px){
                    flex-direction: column;
                }
                
                
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <header id="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="http://www.pngmart.com/files/1/Civil-Engineering-Book-PNG.png" id="header-img" alt="logo of library club">
                </div>    
                
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Our Partners</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're trying to use features commonly found SASS/LESS or CSS-in-JS inside standard CSS.

When you use standard CSS, you media queries must be at the top level and include a valid CSS block made of selectors and definitions.

You can read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  #navbar {
     color: pink; /* valid */
  }
}

#navbar {
  @media (max-width: 300px) {
     color: pink; /* invalid, media nested inside a selector */
  }
}
```

You can also linters to test your CSS, one example online is http://csslint.net